# How to exclude certain category in SQL Statement

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Here's my current codes to get popular post from wordpress wp_post table. How can I exclude those in categories such as 3 or 4?

```
$popularposts = "SELECT ID,post_title FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0,".$pop_posts;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($popularposts);
```

Comment: It would help to see the schema for wp_post

Answer (score 1):

after 'publish' you add (assuming the field for categorie is categorie)

```
and categorie not in ('3', '4')
```

or, if categorie is numeric:

```
and (categorie < 3 or categeorie > 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Dugg through the web and stackoverflow, almost solved the problem. Still I need add

```
ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0,".$pop_posts
```

somewhere in the following code.

```
$popularposts  = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts 
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)  
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)  

WHERE ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id <> 3  
   AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id <> 4  
   AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'   
   AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'  
   AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish')";
```

Comment: Done. ... AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish')
   ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.comment_count DESC LIMIT 0,".$pop_posts;